# Custom Label in a Custom Button (javascript)

Tags: javascript, custom-button, customlabel

I have a custom button that has a custom label:
[image]

for the custom label of sharepointLink: the value has just like this: **url.aspx**

But when clicking the custom button, it shows like this:
[image]

Is it possible to put the custom label in a custom button? If so, is my syntax for the javascript correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the syntax {&Label.sharepointLink} to {!$Label.sharepointLink}

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine. I just tested in my org with a custom label called Label with the following Javascript on a custom button:

```
alert('{!$Label.Label}');
```

The text I had set up was 'Sample' and when I clicked the custom button on my object it correctly alerted the word Sample.

**In your case it seems you are not using correct syntax.**